# Solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ using coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

A line passes through $(4,1),(1,y),$ and $(x,2)$. What is the value of $x$ in terms of $y$?

What equation do  I have to use for this problem? $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ , $y=mx+b$ , $y-b=m(x-a)$ I tried using them, but unable to find the answer, can someone please explain.

Comment: sorry but you just got a elementary problem wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m=\frac{1-y}{4-1}=\frac{1-x}{4-2}$$
$$\implies \frac 13-\frac y3=\frac 12 -\frac x2$$
$$\implies 2-2y=3-3x $$
$$\implies 3x=3-2+2y=1+2y$$
$$\require{enclose}\enclose{box}{x=\frac 13(1+2y)}$$